# anchor tag cant fire click function from display none div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the div with display none style have an anchor tag which will delete that div on click function

for complete code review link it is working on browser but not at jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/eqaxh7d0/

i am appending display none div to another div which is display block so apparently anchor tag will be visible but

but no click function

and for delete i am  using this  code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.close-div').on('click',function() {
       $(this).closest('div#nestedFeilds').remove();
   });     
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is not loaded at linked jsfiddle. If expected result of clicking `<a>` element is to remove the parent element you can append the `.innerHTML` to a `<div>` element attach `click` event to the `<a>` element within `<div>` element, call `event.preventDefault()` within event handler to prevent default action of navigation, and call `$(this).parent().remove()` to remove the dynamically created `<div>` parent element where `.innerHTML` is set

```js
$(function() {
  var i = 0;

  $("#addNew").click(function() {
    i++;
    var maindiv = document.getElementById('nestedFeilds').innerHTML;
    $("#nestedFeilds :input").each(function() {
      var orignalname = $(this).attr('name');
      $(this).attr('name', orignalname.substring(0, orignalname.length - 1) + i);
    });
    $("#showhere").append(
      $("<div>", {"class":"field-parent", html:maindiv})
      .find("a").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent(".field-parent").remove()
      }).end()
    );
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Your Profile</label>
<div class="row" id="mainContainer">
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4">
    <label for="Education">Education</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8  verticalLine" id="nestedFeilds" style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left; display: none">
    <a href="" style="color: red;float:right; ">Delete Education</a>
    <input type="text" placeholder="School Name" class="form-control" id="School_Name" required="" name="School_Name_0">
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Feild of Study" class="form-control" id="feild_Name" required="" name="feild_Name_0">
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Degree" class="form-control" id="Degree_Name" required="" name="Degree_Name_0">
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" id="YearName" style="float:left;" required="" name="first_year_name_0" value=''>
          <option value="2017">2017</option>
          <option value="2016">2016</option>
          <option value="2015">2015</option>
          <option value="2014">2014</option>
          <option value="2013">2013</option>
          <option value="2012">2012</option>
          <option value="2011">2011</option>
          <option value="2010">2010</option>
          <option value="2009">2009</option>
          <option value="2008">2008</option>
          <option value="2007">2007</option>
          <option value="2006">2006</option>
          <option value="2005">2005</option>
          <option value="2004">2004</option>
          <option value="2003">2003</option>
          <option value="2002">2002</option>
          <option value="2001">2001</option>
          <option value="2000">2000</option>
          <option value="1999">1999</option>
          <option value="1998">1998</option>
          <option value="1997">1997</option>
          <option value="1996">1996</option>
          <option value="1995">1995</option>
          <option value="1994">1994</option>
          <option value="1993">1993</option>
          <option value="1992">1992</option>
          <option value="1991">1991</option>
          <option value="1990">1990</option>
          <option value="1989">1989</option>
          <option value="1988">1988</option>
          <option value="1987">1987</option>
          <option value="1986">1986</option>
          <option value="1985">1985</option>
          <option value="1984">1984</option>
          <option value="1983">1983</option>
          <option value="1982">1982</option>
          <option value="1981">1981</option>
          <option value="1980">1980</option>
          <option value="1979">1979</option>
          <option value="1978">1978</option>
          <option value="1977">1977</option>
          <option value="1976">1976</option>
          <option value="1975">1975</option>
          <option value="1974">1974</option>
          <option value="1973">1973</option>
          <option value="1972">1972</option>
          <option value="1971">1971</option>
          <option value="1970">1970</option>
          <option value="1969">1969</option>
          <option value="1968">1968</option>
          <option value="1967">1967</option>
          <option value="1966">1966</option>
          <option value="1965">1965</option>
          <option value="1964">1964</option>
          <option value="1963">1963</option>
          <option value="1962">1962</option>
          <option value="1961">1961</option>
          <option value="1960">1960</option>
          <option value="1959">1959</option>
          <option value="1958">1958</option>
          <option value="1957">1957</option>
          <option value="1956">1956</option>
          <option value="1955">1955</option>
          <option value="1954">1954</option>
          <option value="1953">1953</option>
          <option value="1952">1952</option>
          <option value="1951">1951</option>
          <option value="1950">1950</option>
          <option value="1949">1949</option>
          <option value="1948">1948</option>
          <option value="1947">1947</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" style="margin-left: -20px; float:left;" id="monthName" required="" name="first_Name_month_0" value=''>Select Month

          <option value='01'>January</option>
          <option value='02'>February</option>
          <option value='03'>March</option>
          <option value='04'>April</option>
          <option value='05'>May</option>
          <option value='06'>June</option>
          <option value='07'>July</option>
          <option value='08'>August</option>
          <option value='09'>September</option>
          <option value='10'>October</option>
          <option value='11'>November</option>
          <option value='12'>December</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left: -20px;float:left;">
        <p style="text-align: left; margin-top: 5px">&nbsp;to</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" id="YearName" style="margin-right:30px; float:left;" required="" name="second_year_name_0" value=''>Select Month

          <option value="2017">2017</option>
          <option value="2016">2016</option>
          <option value="2015">2015</option>
          <option value="2014">2014</option>
          <option value="2013">2013</option>
          <option value="2012">2012</option>
          <option value="2011">2011</option>
          <option value="2010">2010</option>
          <option value="2009">2009</option>
          <option value="2008">2008</option>
          <option value="2007">2007</option>
          <option value="2006">2006</option>
          <option value="2005">2005</option>
          <option value="2004">2004</option>
          <option value="2003">2003</option>
          <option value="2002">2002</option>
          <option value="2001">2001</option>
          <option value="2000">2000</option>
          <option value="1999">1999</option>
          <option value="1998">1998</option>
          <option value="1997">1997</option>
          <option value="1996">1996</option>
          <option value="1995">1995</option>
          <option value="1994">1994</option>
          <option value="1993">1993</option>
          <option value="1992">1992</option>
          <option value="1991">1991</option>
          <option value="1990">1990</option>
          <option value="1989">1989</option>
          <option value="1988">1988</option>
          <option value="1987">1987</option>
          <option value="1986">1986</option>
          <option value="1985">1985</option>
          <option value="1984">1984</option>
          <option value="1983">1983</option>
          <option value="1982">1982</option>
          <option value="1981">1981</option>
          <option value="1980">1980</option>
          <option value="1979">1979</option>
          <option value="1978">1978</option>
          <option value="1977">1977</option>
          <option value="1976">1976</option>
          <option value="1975">1975</option>
          <option value="1974">1974</option>
          <option value="1973">1973</option>
          <option value="1972">1972</option>
          <option value="1971">1971</option>
          <option value="1970">1970</option>
          <option value="1969">1969</option>
          <option value="1968">1968</option>
          <option value="1967">1967</option>
          <option value="1966">1966</option>
          <option value="1965">1965</option>
          <option value="1964">1964</option>
          <option value="1963">1963</option>
          <option value="1962">1962</option>
          <option value="1961">1961</option>
          <option value="1960">1960</option>
          <option value="1959">1959</option>
          <option value="1958">1958</option>
          <option value="1957">1957</option>
          <option value="1956">1956</option>
          <option value="1955">1955</option>
          <option value="1954">1954</option>
          <option value="1953">1953</option>
          <option value="1952">1952</option>
          <option value="1951">1951</option>
          <option value="1950">1950</option>
          <option value="1949">1949</option>
          <option value="1948">1948</option>
          <option value="1947">1947</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" id="monthName" style="float:left; margin-left: -20px;" required="" name="Second__Name_month_0" value=''>Select Month

          <option value='01'>January</option>
          <option value='02'>February</option>
          <option value='03'>March</option>
          <option value='04'>April</option>
          <option value='05'>May</option>
          <option value='06'>June</option>
          <option value='07'>July</option>
          <option value='08'>August</option>
          <option value='09'>September</option>
          <option value='10'>October</option>
          <option value='11'>November</option>
          <option value='12'>December</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="2ndmainContainer">
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8  verticalLine" id="showhere" style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left;"></div>
  <div style="margin-left: 120px; float:left;"><a id="addNew"> Add Education</a></div>
</div>
```